# Group by with use of condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following data shown below:

```
    stockid     stockname   units   typeid   stocktype
    321         stn433      gl      2        
    433         stn433      gl      2
    432         stn433      gl      2         pick
    544         stn664      gl      1         
    533         stn664      gl      1
    655         stn555      gl      3         pick
    677         stn555      gl      3
```

Based on a stockname, units, typeid combination (group by stockname, units, typeid), if there are any values of 'pick' for the stocktype, use that stockid or else choose the minimum stockid for the combination.

I have shown below what the output should look like. I know I can easily do a group by stockname, units, typeid and then get the min(stockid) but I need to check if there are any with value of 'pick' first if so choose that one else choose the min(sotckid). I could not figure out how to do that. Thank you in advance.

Note: The output below is **grouped** by stockname, units, typeid showing the appropriate stockid.

OUTPUT:

```
    stockid     stockname   units   typeid
    432         stn433      gl      2
    533         stn664      gl      1
    655         stn555      gl      3
```

I am using SQL Server 2016 - TSql.

Comment: And what happened to stock `stn555`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE(stockid INT, stockname VARCHAR(10), units VARCHAR(20), typeid INT, stocktype VARCHAR(20) )

INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES
    (321         ,'stn433','gl',      2, NULL),        
    (433         ,'stn433','gl',      2, NULL),
    (432         ,'stn433','gl',      2, 'pick'),
    (544         ,'stn664','gl',      1, NULL),         
    (533         ,'stn664','gl',      1, NULL),
    (655         ,'stn555','gl',      3, 'pick'),
    (677         ,'stn555','gl',      3, NULL)


;WITH PickTable AS (
    SELECT MIN(stockid) stockid, stockname,   units,   typeid  FROM @SampleData
    WHERE stocktype ='pick'
    GROUP BY stockname,   units,   typeid
)
,NotPickTable
AS (
    SELECT MIN(stockid) stockid, stockname,   units,   typeid  FROM @SampleData T
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM PickTable P WHERE P.stockname = T.stockname AND P.units= T.units AND  P.typeid = T.typeid )
    GROUP BY stockname,   units,   typeid
)
SELECT * FROM PickTable
UNION 
SELECT * FROM NotPickTable
```

Comment: sarslan, I want to use SELECT * FROM PickTable
UNION 
SELECT * FROM NotPickTable incorporated in CTE table. How do that?

Comment: Just replace the last union select with this query.

,UniTable AS (
 SELECT * FROM PickTable
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM NotPickTable
)
SELECT * FROM UniTable

Answer (score 0):

I didnt fully understand the question but i would say you need to use a case statement

```
     CASE WHEN stocktype = 'pick' group by.....
     ELSE min(sotckid)
     END
```

Comment: you may possibly need a case statement with a partition by in depending on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by stockname, units, typeid
                                order by (case when stocktype = 'pick' then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Gordon, I sorry that was my mistake. Look at the original table. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without `CASE`

```
SELECT * FROM stack WHERE stocktype = 'pick'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM stack
WHERE stockid IN
(
   SELECT MIN(stockid) FROM stack 
   WHERE stockname NOT IN (
     SELECT stockname FROM stack WHERE stocktype = 'pick'
   )
   GROUP BY stockname
)
```

Comment: Hi Radim, I need to do a group by stockname, units, typeid and then show the stockid for the group based on if it first round any with 'pick' then choose that stockid for the group or else choose the min(stockid) from the group. Anyway you can revise your query to do that and show only the stockid, stockname,units, typeid fields based on the combination.

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple query, which gets desired result:

```
select case when IsPick is NULL then minStockId else StockId end AS stockid,
       stockname, units, typeid
from (
    select  min(stocktype) AS IsPick, 
            max(case when stocktype is not null then stockid end) AS StockId,
            min(stockid) AS minStockId,
            stockname,
            units,
            typeid
    from @x
    group by  stockname, units, typeid
) AS A
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the answer as sarslan but now i post it :)

```
with data as(
SELECT [Stockid]
  ,[StockName]
  ,[units]
  ,[typeid]
  ,[stocktype]
  ,case when stocktype IS not null then 1 else 0 end as Flag
FROM [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[stock]
)

,picks as (
select min([Stockid]) as StockID
  ,[StockName]
  ,[units]
  ,[typeid]
  from data
  where Flag = 1
  group by Stockname,units,typeid
 )


,nopicks as (
select MIN(a.stockid) as Stockid,a.StockName,a.Units,a.typeid from data  a 
where a.Flag= 0 and not exists (select typeid from picks b where a.typeid = 
b.typeid)


group by a.stockname,a.units,a.typeid
)
Select * from picks
union all
select * from nopicks
```